# Existing PostgreSQL database used in Pyramid

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Can someone point to me the relevant documentation that I need to read in order for me to understand how to connect and query an already existing PostgreSQL database which was created outside of Pyramid? 
I'm working on a project and my part is to create the web app while a friend is thinking about the database design (he also creates the tables structures). 
What I would like is to import in some way the whole structure he created without having to recreate the tables in my models.py document.

Hope this makes sense

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Your problem is not directly related to Pyramid. You can use sqlalchemy however you want. You should probably look in the direction of "how to use sqlalchemy with an existing database".

Comment: Take a look at [Reflecting Database Objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/reflection.html) (read first paragraph). If you are just starting, an easier way in would be to try this with `Declarative` extension. Read [Using Reflection with Declarative](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#using-reflection-with-declarative) for intro.

Comment: Thanks a lot van... That should be enough to get me started in the right direction